# Can a user receive push notifications from a "added to home" PWA after a device reboot?

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps

From my researches, creating a PWA with the ability of receiving push notifications is pretty straightforward.

But what happens if the user **reboots the device**? Will the app (previously added to home screen, and thus downloaded) able to already receive push notification or the user will have to re-open the app at least once (to start the background service worker)?

If not, there is a way to restart a service worker automagically after device reboot?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried. Also, check [Adding Push Notifications to a Web App](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/) to get started with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea that you would restart a service worker at runtime is a complete misunderstanding of service worker architecture.

The whole concept is they are short lived processes, invoked in response to an event and terminated upon completion of their task.

Receiving notifications via the Push API is dependent upon the browser process running, not your specific PWA. Notification subscription endpoints point at browser specific servers which cannot be changed, eg chrome endpoints all start `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/....`

Your application server posts push notifications to these servers, which in turn push them to your subscribers browsers. The browser then launches the relevant service worker which invokes the processes within its push event listener. Once the `event.waitUntil` promise resolves the service worker exits.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to open the app after reboot or keep it in the background explicitly to receive push notifications. Its part of web standard and works without manually intervention. iOS support is still limited. You can read more about it [here](https://whatwebcando.today/push-notifications.html).